# Is there a (sane) way to get all custom fields for a post, which do not have a leading underscore?

Tags: custom-field

I know about `get_post_custom()`, but that returns *all* custom fields, including those with a leading underscore. Is there a reasonable way to get only the ones without a leading underscore? Would I just have to resort to using `get_post_custom()` plus a regex to parse the results?

Comment: Meta keys are meta keys whether they have underscore or not so if you look in the database that is how it is layed out so there is no other way other than to pull all of the keys out and then filter out the ones without underscores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can write your own function to do the matching at the SQL level
2. Grab all of the keys and process them in PHP. You shouldn't need regex. Simple string functions should do it.
3. Don't bother processing the results at all and instead just use the
   keys you need and ignore the rest-- something like `echo $meta['key'];`
4. Just ask for the particular key you want using [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

I doubt that #1 is going to be faster than #2, especially taking into account the built in caching. #3 should perform about as well as #2, given that same built in caching.

I don't know what isn't 'sane' about those options.

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I didn't think of #2. That seems sane to me. Speed isn't an issue, this is just for convenient debugging/development usage.

Answer (score 0):

This is adapted from the example in [get_post_custom_keys()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_keys#Examples).

```
function get_public_custom_fields( $post_id = 0 ) {
    if ( ! empty( $post_id ) )
        $custom_fields = get_post_custom( $post_id );
    else
        $custom_fields = get_post_custom();

    $public_custom_fields = array();
    foreach ( $custom_fields as $key => $value ) {
        if ( '_' != $key{0} )
            $public_custom_fields[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $public_custom_fields;
}
```